# confusion about arithmetic sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

The question is this:  in the arithmetic sequence $ 3,7,11,...$, find the least value of $n$ for which the sum of the first $2n$ terms will exceed the sum of the first $n$ terms by $155$.

What is wrong with my solution?

Sum of $n$ terms:  $n/2( 4n+2) $

Sum of $2n$ terms:  $ 4n^2+2n $

Final equation:  $2n^2+n-155=0$

I am not getting $5$ for $n$; please help.

Comment: the formula for the sum of $n$ terms should depend on the initial term ($3$ in this case)

Comment: please solve it, ive been struggling for a while now

Comment: when $n=1$, what is the sum of the first $2n$ terms?

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with your solution is that the sum of the first $n$ terms of the [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

$3,7,11,...$ with initial term $3$ and difference $4$ is $\dfrac n2(2\times3+(n-1)4)=2n^2+n,$

so the sum of the first $2n$ terms is $2(2n)^2+(2n)=\color{red}8n^2+2n$.

Can you solve it now?

Comment: yes, thank you so much!